# How to read the file which is in other directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My project

```
et->datacollector
  ->eventprocessor->multilang->resources->python->tenderevent->rules->Table.py
                  ->target->inpout->Read.csv
```

Table.py

```
import pandas as pd
df_LFB1 = pd.read_csv('Read.csv', sep = ',', usecols = [1,2,7,59])
```

Now above I want to use `Read.csv` file how should I give the directory of `Read.csv` file in `pd.read_csv`

Comment: can you please suggest me what was wrong with the question

Comment: `target/inpout/Read.csv` this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.getcwd()
Out[42]: '/Users/Documents'
## os.path.abspath(__file__) ## inside script
```

If I have the `'Read.csv'` file in my current working directory `'/Users/Documents'`, I can read the file like below.

```
df_LFB1 = pd.read_csv('Read.csv', sep = ',', usecols = [1,2,7,59])
```

and if my file is not in current working dierctory but in some other directory lets say `et` directory is in `/home/project`,

```
df_LFB1 = pd.read_csv(r'/home/project/et/eventprocessor/target/inpout/ Read.csv',
                                     sep = ',', usecols = [1,2,7,59])
```

Above statement will read the file.

Note: when you provide absolute path to file. It doesnt not matter where your script resides.